# python: convert rows formatted file in csv files to import in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lot of txt files formatted in this way:

```
oranges
apples
ananas
bananas

23
45
65
67

45
46
54
34

45
67
54
34
```

....... **the number of rows can change in different files**...

How can I obtain  comma separated files formatted this way ?:

```
oranges apples ananas bananas
23 45 65 67
45 46 54 34
45 67 54 34
```

............

So I can use data in a pandas dataframe ?

My code attempt thus far:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "http://www.ererreer.com/eeeee.csv"
a = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you run into any issues? Try Googling for how to read files in Python, working on data line by line. How to modify and work on lists and strings. These are all basic things you should learn first before trying to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

Using the newer `regex` module that supports empty splits:

```
import regex as re
rx = re.compile(r'(?V1)^$', re.M)

csv_like = "\n".join(
       [part.strip().replace('\n', ',') 
        for part in rx.split(data) if part])
print(csv_like)
```

---

This yields

```
oranges,apples,ananas,bananas
23,45,65,67
45,46,54,34
45,67,54,34
```

And can then be piped into a `pandas` dataframe.